# how i can read multilevel json in selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

JSON File:

```
{
   "layout": {
      "user": {
         "pages": {
             "Home": {
                "sub_domain_name": "abcd",
                   "title": "Home",
                    "page_id": 1111111,
                    "is_login_required": false,
                    "description": "Description",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "desktop": [
                        {
                            "name": "row",
                            "component_id": "31fac419-f1ff-4614",
                            "main_classes": "border-bottom-0 me",
                            "child": [
                                {
                                    "name": "col",
                                    "component_id": "087851bc",
                                    "component_name": "Card",
                                    "size": "12",
                                    "main_classes": "-",
                                    "classes": "display-6",
                                    "height": "-",
                                    "width": "-",
                                    "items": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }

    **python code:**
```

import json
myJsonFile=open("config-2.json")`open json file`
jsondata=myJsonFile.read()`read json file`
#parse
obj=json.loads(jsondata)`store json data in object`
list=obj['layout']`read first node`
print("Length:",len(list))
for i in list:
inner_page=list[i]['pages']`read pages node`
pages_list=inner_page.keys()
for j in pages_list:
desktop=inner_page[j]['desktop']`read desktop node`
print(desktop)`print desktop node`
for k in desktop:
print("Component Name:",k['name'])
i want to read component_name from child

Comment: Please provide All code fromated in a codeblock

Answer (score 0):

should be possible using:

```py
print(ob["layout"]["user"]["pages"]["Home"]["desktop"][0]["child"][0]["component_name"])
```

Which should return: `"Card"`

Answer (score -1):

You have to select the item that is `[0]` and check the name from the `dict`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
import json
myJsonFile=open("config-2.json")
jsondata=myJsonFile.read()
obj=json.loads(jsondata)
dict_process=obj['layout']
for i in dict_process:
    inner_page=dict_process[i]['pages']
    pages_list=inner_page.keys()
    for j in pages_list:
        desktop=inner_page[j]['desktop']
        child_keys=desktop[0]['child']
        for k in child_keys:
            print (k['component_name'])
```

Output:

```
Card
```

**EDIT 2 as per request:**

Note: there is one more `for loop` based on length of dictionary `desktop`.

```
import json
myJsonFile=open("config-2_new.json")
jsondata=myJsonFile.read()
obj=json.loads(jsondata)
dict_process=obj['layout']
for i in dict_process:
    inner_page=dict_process[i]['pages']
    pages_list=inner_page.keys()
    for j in pages_list:
        desktop=inner_page[j]['desktop']
        for x in range(0,len(desktop)):
            child_keys=desktop[x]['child']
            for k in child_keys:
                print (k['component_name'])
```

**Output:**

```
Card
Author
```

Comment: Poor practice to use "list" as an object name (as it's a Python type name) plus in your code "list" is actually a dictionary

Comment: This is work .but how it use for multiple rows?

Comment: @PoojaPatil Post some examples? What do you mean by multiple rows?

Comment: @SivaShanmugam I want "component_name": "Author" in above json file

Comment: @SivaShanmugam when we use this foe multiple node then it not works...Nodes means like "Home" another one like "Contact"

Comment: And also when we added another node like desktop we add Mobile the how it work

Comment: yes this answer is helpful